# Is it possible to separate "by" from "by which" in these two cases?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality, usage

> There's no other standard by which to compare yourself to.
>
> Competition provides a benchmark by which to compare yourself to and
>   be better than, and forces a company to prepare and think much in the
>   same manner a football team prepares to run faster, be stronger and
>   outsmart the opponent.

I've read many articles about [Preposition + Which] and most of them talk about how we can put the preposition at the end of the sentence without stating when we can or can't actually do that.

My biggest question is not only just about the usage and the grammar of [By which] but those of all other Preposition-which's. That said, my recent encounters of them are mostly [By which], at least that is what I can recall, and the two quoted sentences above are what I actually found after reading/listening to multiple online resources.

So, back on the topic, if we were going to move the position of "by" to another position in the two sentences, where should we place it? The following alternatives do not look okay to me.

> There's no other standard which to compare yourself to by.
>
> Competition provides a benchmark which to compare yourself to by and
>   be better than, and forces a company to prepare and think much in the
>   same manner a football team prepares to run faster, be stronger and
>   outsmart the opponent.

Comment: It's bad English. You don't compare yourself _by_ something, but _to_ or _with_ it. The expression should be either _to compare yourself to_ or  better still _with which to compare yourself_.

Comment: @KateBunting Do you mean the original sentences are bad English, or the alternatives I proposed?

Comment: I meant the original sentence(s), but your versions, as you say yourself, don't work either. _By_ doesn't belong here.

Comment: @KateBunting  If _by_ being replaced with _with_, would the original sentences be _There's no other standard with which to compare yourself to_ and _Competition provides a benchmark with which to compare yourself to..._? Do we need to leave out the _to_ after _yourself_ in both cases?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in my original comment! You compare something _either_ with something else _or_ to something else, not both.

Comment: @KateBunting Could we also say _to which to compare yourself_?

Comment: Yes, I have told you that you can say _compare to_, so of course you can use _to_ in the inverted form as well.